# Materialize sideNav from multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I'm using Materialize's sideNav() jQuery plugin to toggle the side nav open and close. It works fine with one button.

When using multiple buttons, it works the first time through for each button but then only the last button works on the first click. All the previous buttons require two clicks.

Here's the html:

```
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="btn button-collapse">Button One</a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="btn button-collapse">Button Two</a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="btn button-collapse">Button Three</a>

  <!-- sideNav -->
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
    <li>Hello side nav</li>
  </ul>
```

Steps to reproduce:

- Click "Button One" (sideNav opens)
- Click "Button Two" (sideNav opens)
- Click "Button Three" (sideNav opens)
- Click "Button One" (nothing)
- Click "Button One" (sideNav opens)
- Click "Button Two" (nothing)
- Click "Button Two" (sideNav opens)
- Click "Button Three" (sideNav opens)

And the jQuery:

```
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({ edge: 'right' });
```

I've tried clearing the function before the click, wrapping the event inside of ready(), and assigning IDs to each button element and hard coding that to the jQuery event but still doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/heFhKdg6z9iNiamzGwS4?p=preview).

Comment: Are you trying to trigger the same sideNav() with all those buttons? or are you planning to have 3 sideNavs? because the sideNav()function acccepts only one element trigger.

Comment: @SergioAlen Thanks for your comment. I wanted to have one sideNav but  if it only accepts one element trigger I'm okay with having 3. Have an idea of what that might look like?